# Query a recordset object using VBA

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003, recordset

I'm using Access 2003 and have a form that allows the user to pick from a variety of filters, and I use VBA to update the recordset of a subform based on those filters (I generate a SQL statement in VBA).  This subform can have duplicate client ids, and now I'm trying to get to a unique list of client ids.

Is there any easy way to query out the unique client ids using VBA if I have the source SQL for the subform?  I've thought of these options:

- Write all the ids to a temp table and then query that table (seems
  like more work/resources than are necessary)
- Somehow apply a query to a recordset object in VBA (is this possible?);  I'd set the recordset object equal to the SQL query and then try to run a `SELECT DISTINCT client_id FROM <the recordset object>`, but I'm not finding any information that leads me to believe this is possible
- Generate a new SQL query based on the original one (I was hoping `SELECT DISTINCT client_id FROM ('original select query text here')` would work, but it gave me a syntax error in the FROM statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aim for the third alternative.  This should work if you alias the subquery, and `'original select query text here'` can fit.

```
SELECT DISTINCT sub.client_id
FROM
    (
        'original select query text here'
    ) AS sub
```

If Access still chokes, show us what you have for `'original select query text here'`.

You're right about alternative #1 ... that is wasteful.

Alternative #2 is not possible because Access won't let you run a query using a recordset object as the `FROM` source.